# Язык С: функция, проверяющая, что в "char-массив" занесено число из диапазона [1; 65535] (иными словами - число типа unsigned short int)

Tags: c, массивы, строки, функции, числа

Мне необходимо получить беззнаковое короткое число, которое я потом хочу использовать как число (в различных алгебраических вычислениях).

Проверять, являются ли введённые данные каким-то числом или, скажем так, "уродой" (примеры: *1h1; h... 23f5; hhh; 1,2; 1,h2* и так далее), как мне кажется, проще, если рассматривать одномерный массив char элементов, из которого при соблюдении определённых условий с использованием функции перевода **atoi** мы получим нужное число.

В своей программе я осуществил защиту от некорректного ввода в те переменные, где ввод ограничен более существенно (например, в переменную *a* мне нужно ввести конкретное вещественное число (0,1) - тут проверку на ввод сделать было проще); в переменную *b* - иное число (1)). Но для переменной ***n*** (где число должно принимать значение из диапазона соответствующего типа (*unsigned short int*)) защиту мне написать не удалось. Пробовал написать цикл, в котором *if atoi(c) !=1 и n не входит в диапазон от 1 до 65535 (уже как int)*, то вводим строку (а именно - число, которое хотим перевести) заново. Но такие простенькие условия обрываются при вводе, например, *1h23c* (или в вычислениях используется число до первой буквы (что логично, исходя из условия atoi(c) !=1. Есть понимание, что мне нужно "выудить" из строки, но не могу представить алгоритм защиты от "корявого" ввода в этом случае (возможно, опыта мало).

Надеюсь, "профи" подскажут мне, как действовать, или наведут на мысль - буду благодарен. Моя программа (или, как некоторые называют, "говно-код") с некоторыми комментариями представлена ниже:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <locale.h>

int fact(int k) //факториал через рекурсию
{
    if (k == 0 || k == 1) return 1;
    else return k * fact(k - 1);
}

int check_fl_a(char* c) // защитный ввод переменной a (должна быть =0,1)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    if (c[0] == '0') cnt++;
    if (c[1] == ',') cnt++;
    if (c[2] == '1') cnt++;
    if (c[3] == '\0') cnt++;
    if (cnt == 4) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int check_shint_b(char* c) // защитный ввод переменной b (должна быть =1)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    if (c[0] == '1') cnt++;
    if (c[1] == '\0') cnt++;
    if (cnt == 2) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

int check_shint_n1(int chislo) // одно из условий "корректности" введённого числа в char-строку
{         // возможно, можно написать второе условие на "не-цифры", посимвольно проверяя строку   
    if (chislo >= 1 && chislo <= 65535) return 1;
    else return 0;
}

char* get_string(unsigned short* len) 
{
    *len = 0; // изначально строка пуста
    int cap = 1; // ёмкость контейнера динамической строки (1, так как точно будет '\0')
    char* c = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)); // динамическая пустая строка
    char ch = getchar(); // символ для чтения данных
    // читаем символы, пока не получим символ переноса строки (\n)
    while (ch != '\n') {
        c[(*len)++] = ch; // заносим в строку новый символ
        // если реальный размер больше размера контейнера, то увеличим его размер
        if (*len >= cap) 
        {
            cap *= 2; // увеличиваем ёмкость строки в два раза
            c = (char*)realloc(c, cap * sizeof(char)); // создаём новую строку с увеличенной ёмкостью  
        }
        ch = getchar(); // считываем следующий символ          
    }
    c[*len] = '\0'; // завершаем строку символом конца строки
    return c; // возвращаем указатель на считанную строку
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "ru");
    float a, h;
    double y, s, x, r, w;
    unsigned short int b, n, k, rm;
    char* c = NULL;

    do {
        printf("Введите a (=0,1): ");
        c = get_string(&rm);
        a = atof(c);
    } while (check_fl_a(c) != 1);
    free(c);

    do {
        printf("Введите b (=1): ");
        c = get_string(&rm);
        b = atoi(c);
    } while (check_shint_b(c) != 1);
    free(c);

    h = a;

    do {
        printf("Введите n: "); //проблемное место программы
        c = get_string(&rm);
        n = atoi(c);
    } while (check_shint_n1(n) !=1);

    printf("\n");
    printf("Таблица:\n");
    printf("\n");
    for (x = a; x <= b; x += h)
    {
        r = 1;
        s = 0;
        for (k = 0; k <= n; k++)
        {
            r = ((pow(k, 2) + 1) / fact(k)) * pow(x / 2, k);
            s += r;
        }
        y = ((pow(x, 2) / 4) + (x / 2) + 1) * exp(x / 2);
        w = fabs(y - s);  
        printf("x = %lf\t Y(x) = %lf\t S(x) = %lf\t |Y(x)-S(x)| = %lf\n", x, y, s, w);
    }
}
```

Comment: Для переменной n проверьте, что строка состоит исключительно из цифр и её размер не превышает 5.  Обратите внимание, что в вашем коде происходит утечка памяти, когда не проходит проверка введенной переменной.

Comment: @СергейСимонов я набросал функцию, проверяющую, есть ли в строке что-то, кроме цифр - она вроде как хорошо работает. я, чтобы просто проверить, будет ли работать такая функция, сделал размер строки фиксированным ( то есть просто присвоил его равным 5 ). можете подсказать, как мне проверять размер строки, если он произвольный и формируется в функции get_string??

int check_str(char* str)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (isdigit(str[i]) == 0) {
            cnt++;
        }
    }
    if (cnt == 0) return 1;
    else return 0;
}